# Problem to filter results using CONTAINS on primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I'm with a specific problem using primefaces, as you know filters on primefaces may use the option contains on filterMatchMode 'filterMatchMode="contains"', but when I trigger the action I'm getting this error: ERROR TypeError: filter.toLowerCase is not a function.
This errors occurs because is not possible use tolowercase with arrays as you can see.

[image: Debug error]
Does anyone got this error or know how to solve?

Thanks

Comment: PrimeFaces has no relation to angular whatsoever. Please improve your question by reading [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Normally it is good practice to  post code as text and not as images. But the code you show seems to be **your** code (or does PF actually somewhere have 'Administrador' and 'Cedente' etc in their javascript? So I'm inclined to say: "why do **you** do a `filter.toLowerCase()`?